# How to insert sales order data to user-defined table

Tags: sapb1

How to insert Sales order data like docEntry, object type to user-defined table using data event (using C#) or any other way in SAP B1.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show code that you have tried? If you install, SAP B1 SDK, there are code samples you can follow.

Comment: Hello, there are 2 ways of doing it. One by using a UI addon and capturing the form_data_add event and the other by modifying the post transaction notification directly on the database without the use of addons. Could you specify which way you would prefer so we can help?

Comment: Hi,I have tried below code a& it's working now. string DocEntry = oForm.DataSources.DBDataSources.Item(0).GetValue("DocEntry", offset);  oForm.Mode == SAPbouiCOM.BoFormMode.fm_ADD_MODE || oForm.Mode == SAPbouiCOM.BoFormMode.fm_UPDATE_MODE oUserTable.UserFields.Fields.Item("U_barcode").Value = oEditTxt.String; oUserTable.UserFields.Fields.Item("U_pdocentry").Value = DocEntry;

Comment: Hi Vyron, How to capture form_data_add event and form_data_update event? I want to run this code on form data update event.

Answer (score 0):

check this code:

```
UserTable oUserTable = null;
oUserTable = conexionSAP.oCompany.UserTables.Item("TABLE_NAME");
oUserTable.Code = "2";
oUserTable.Name = "SUPER_SACO";
oUserTable.UserFields.Fields.Item("USER_FIELD1").Value = "9746";
oUserTable.UserFields.Fields.Item("USER_FIELD2").Value = "1084.00";
oUserTable.Add()
```

see you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).